# cannot set values to ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic application that send from values to server. I want to fill the text filed values from the controller. But though i get values in controller i am not able to show the values in text field.

My HTML area is:

```
<ion-item>
              <ion-label><ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon></ion-label>
              <ion-input [(ngModel)]="collegename" placeholder="College name" type="text" value="{{selectedcollegename}}"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
```

Angular code:

```
export class MessagePage {
  name: string; 
  id: string; 
  collegename: string = '';
  description: string = '';
  loading: any;
  selectedcollegename: string='';
  selectedcollegeid: string='';
  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public apiService: ApiServiceProvider, public authService: Auth,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.name = navParams.get('name');
    this.id = navParams.get('id');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.selectedcollegename = this.name;
    this.selectedcollegeid = this.id;
    console.log("selectedcollegename name is "+this.selectedcollegename);
    console.log("selectedcollege id is "+this.selectedcollegeid);
  }
}
```

Console error:

[image]

**I UPDATED THE CODE AS**:

changed the

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedcollegename = this.name;
    this.selectedcollegeid = this.id;
    console.log("selectedcollegename name is "+this.selectedcollegename);
    console.log("selectedcollege id is "+this.selectedcollegeid);
  }
```

Now i didnt get any errors but no values are shown in tex field.

**UPDATE**

I removed the **[(ngModel)]** now it works.. but i need ngmodel there.. what am i missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the value attribute, just use [(ngModel)]="selectedcollegename" and you don't need to set the id and name in the constructor and then set again in ngOnInit. Just set selectedcollegename and selectedcollegeid in the constructor.

Another thing. When you need to bind any value from the component in an attribute, you must to use the attribute with the square brackets like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your HTML like

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label><ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon></ion-label>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="collegename" placeholder="College name" type="text"></ion-input>
```

In your Constructor

```
constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public apiService: ApiServiceProvider, public authService: Auth,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
this.name = navParams.get('name');
this.collegename = navParams.get('name');
 this.id = navParams.get('id');
  }
```